# making a web services query using gSoap with query arguments

Tags: c++, xml, visual-c++, gsoap

I'm attempting to convert a soap query written for C# into a gSoap query in Visual C++.

The C# query adds an XML node's to the query call, in order to pass parameters to the query:

```
XmlNode queryOpts = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "QueryOptions", "");
queryOpts.InnerXml = "<DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc>";
```

Here's the C# query, passing various args (some args are specified as XmlNode objects)

```
XmlNode nodeListItems = listService.GetListItems("Announcements", null, query, viewFields, null, queryOpts, null);
```

The C++ / gSoap query allows me to pass a query and response object:

```
listService.__ns10__GetListItems(&announcementQuery, &announcementResponse)
```

The query object has various properties that can be set that relate to the arguments in the C# call:

```
announcementQuery.listName  
announcementQuery.query   
announcementQuery.queryOptions 
announcementQuery.viewFields
```

The first argument there is a string, no problem.

The query, queryOptions and viewFields are a bit confusing.

"query" is a class of type _ns2__GetListItems_query, and it has the following functions & members:

```
soap_default()
soap_get()
soap_in()
soap_out()
soap_put()
soap_serialize()
soap_type()
__any
__mixed
```

for query, queryOptions and viewFields, I'd simply like to specify an xml formatted string, like the C# code does, but I'm not sure how this is done.

Can someone cast some experience on this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you've already discovered the answer to this, but I'll post some notes for posterity.

Here's a simple C++ demo for sending and XML doc to a ASP.NET web method.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Service1SoapProxy proxy;

    _WebServiceNS1__HelloWorld helloWorld;
    _WebServiceNS1__HelloWorld_xml xml;
    _WebServiceNS1__HelloWorldResponse response;

    xml.__any = "<doc><x>hi</x></doc>";
    helloWorld.xml = &xml;

    int result = proxy.HelloWorld(&helloWorld, &response);
    fprintf(stdout, "result: %i\n", result);

    switch(result)
    {
        case SOAP_OK:
            fprintf(stdout, "Response: %s\n", response.HelloWorldResult);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the trivial web method in the .NET service:

```
[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld(XmlNode xml)
{
    return string.Format("Your XML: {0}", xml.OuterXml);
}
```

If everything works, you'll see "Response: hi" on your console.